# Scalar field visualisation in R

Tags: r, visualization

I have a table with 3 columns

```
x y f
-101.0  -101.0  0.0172654144157
...
```

`x` and `y` are coordinates. `f` is value.
I want to make a 2d picture, where `x` and `y` are coordinates and `f` is a colour. But I need this picture to be not a number of coloured points, but a continuous schedule.
Help me someone please

Comment: Do you have a regular grid of x and y values?

Comment: Read about methods of 2-d interpolation. If these are 2d points on something like a map, read the R Spatial Task View.

Comment: You could take a look at some posts under the [spatial-interpolation] tag, although this problem is not specific to spatial data.

Comment: `lattice::wiregrid` and similar functions have a "shade" argument that will color in the entire 3D map for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of simple ways to do this if you have a regular grid with your data. Try:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(lattice)

# make some data
s = 100
i = 0.5
x0 <- 27
y0 <- 34
df <- expand.grid(x=seq(0,s,i), y=seq(0,s,i))
df <- transform(df, f = cos( 10*pi * sqrt((x - x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2)))

# try as points
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=f)) + geom_point()

# or as tile
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill=f)) + geom_tile()

# or even easier with lattice
levelplot(f ~ x * y, df)
```

Output examples:

[image]

[image]